# Instance method 'mapView(_:didFailToLocateUserWithError:)' nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, mapkit

I'm using `MKMapView` in my app and it works correctly. I can get the updated position through didUpdate userLocation method correctly.

My problem is this:

> Instance method 'mapView(_:didFailToLocateUserWithError:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'mapView(_:didFailToLocateUserWithError:)' of protocol 'MKMapViewDelegate'

**Notes**:

- I have written the method exactly as below:

  ```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didFailToLocateUserWithError error: Error) {
      //code
  }
  ```
- I have implemented the correct protocol: `MKMapViewDelegate`.
- The method `didUpdateUserLocation` works properly.
- I'm using Xcode 9.2, Deployment Target: 10.0, Swift 3.2.
- I have added @nonobjc at the method signature and the warning doesn't appear, but the method is never executed.

Comment: failure may not happened

Comment: instead it happens, all the MKMapViewDelegate methods are ok if implemented, except this that i strongly need

Answer (score 0):

make sure of this added

```
 mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

and check authorization

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
} else if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() ==   .authorizedWhenInUse {
   mapView.showsUserLocation = true
} else {
   //show alert
}
```

Comment: yes, i did it, in fact the method didUpdate userLocation is accessed properly.